Close all subgroups, programmatically
I know the key code for closing all subgroups (Ctrl+}), as well as doing it by hand from the menu.
But how do I do this programmatically?
adTHANXvance.

This seems to work:
SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Notebook];
FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseAllGroups"]


Worked like a charm -- TYVM!
